# Disable Kartik Gridview responsive on mobile

Tags: gridview, yii2

I used Kartik GridView on my Yii2 webpage (Left). 
I want to keep table format like as demo of Kartik Gridview as below (Right)

[image]
[image]

View.php

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProviderSanChu,
    'filterModel' => $searchModelSanChu,
    'bordered' => true,
    'striped' => false,
    'responsive'=>false,
    'floatHeader'=>false,
    'containerOptions'=>['style'=>'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
    'headerRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'persistResize'=>false,
    'pjax'=>true,
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is:
responsiveWrap: boolean, whether the grid table columns will be responsively wrapped to a single column for small screen devices (less than 480px). Defaults to false.

```
'responsiveWrap' => false,
```

Answer (score 0):

> `responsiveWrap`: boolean, whether the grid table columns will be
>   responsively wrapped to a single column for small screen devices (less
>   than 480px). Defaults to `true`.

Read more [here](http://demos.krajee.com/grid).

Comment: How it's different from existing answer except link and default value (I guess it was changed in extension over time)? It's better to suggest edit to existing answer and improve it by adding links, update deprecated information, etc. instead of creating almost duplicate answer.